# How do I get "appointment slots" from Google Calendar to show up in desktop Fantastical / iOS Fantastical?

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization

I've created "appointment slots" in the Google Calendar web-interface; they show up as events with a little 'four-square' icon next to their name:

[image]

Unfortunately, these 'events' aren't showing up in external calendar applications, like [Fantastical](https://flexibits.com/fantastical) for macOS:

[image]

How, exactly, is one intended to work with "appointment slots?" Does anybody have a suggested workflow, especially if you aren't someone who ever opens the actual *Google* webapp or interacts with it in any way?

Answer (score -1):

You can invite yourself to the appointment slot and the event will show up in Fantastical.